# Latex Enumerate like 1, 2, 3, 2.1, 3.1, 2.2, 3.2, etc

Tags: enumerate, algorithms

This is what I want to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 
        \item
        \item
        \item[2.1]
        \item[3.1]
        \item[2.2]
        \item[3.2]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Below is what we get when we run this code.

[image]

As you can see, I hard-coded this to achieve the result that I want. Do you know a better solution?

For context, I'm thinking of doing this numbering to give a concrete example that shows how to perform a given algorithm that has a loop. In the algorithm, it loops certain steps like steps 2 and 3, that's why I thought of numbering it like a loop as well. If you have any suggestion on how to better number this, I would welcome them, as well.

Thank you.

Comment: So `2.1` is indicating that it's step 2, but again?  I would think you would just want a plain `2`.

Comment: You could use itemize instead of enumerate, since your labels are almost randomized (unless you are reading numbers from right to left and 1 means 1.0).

Comment: We need more detail in terms of context here, perhaps through an example, to understand correctly how the numbering works.

Comment: You can setlist with enumitem package.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{scratch}
\newcommand\repeatableitem[1]{%
    \newcounter{recycle@#1}%
    \item\label{#1}}
\newcommand\repeatitem[1]{%
    \stepcounter{recycle@#1}%
    \item[\ref{#1}\textsubscript{\arabic{recycle@#1}}.]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 
        \repeatableitem{stepA}
        \repeatableitem{stepB}
        \item
        \repeatitem{stepA}
        \repeatitem{stepB}
        \repeatitem{stepA}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]